# AngularJS : Detect form changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm developing an angular app, where I have to check the form changes, and perform some operation depending upon the changes. I know, this can be achieved using `$scope.watch` but that would cost me performance.

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I've a pre-populated form and I will take the form data as a reference using `angular.copy()` and compare with original data.

I had also tried `$parsers` to check, but failed. So, is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: what are you watching for changes?

Comment: I watching for form elements (input,select,radio etc).

Comment: use $scope.$watch...

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) and [this one](http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/11/using-ng-change-instead-of-$watch-in-angular/).

Comment: Could you use ng-pristine and ng-dirty?

Comment: @sjokkogutten- No, because initially the form will be auto populated and the form state will be prisitine. If I make some change in form and revert it back to original the form will be dirty, and in actual case the form value hasn't change because I've reverted it back.

Comment: @AndreaM16 - I've a form where i have above 10 textfield and some select boxes. So according to you, I've to add ng-change to each form element. But, I actually want to avoid it and place the directive at one place like form, and observe changes from there.

Comment: It would be nice if you could put ng-change on a form but its not possible. The best you can do is have ng-change on every textfield but the nice thing is you could use one function in the controller to handle the changes.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ng-change`.

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) - "*Evaluate the given expression when the user changes the input. The expression is evaluated immediately, unlike the JavaScript onchange event which only triggers at the end of a change (usually, when the user leaves the form element or presses the return key).*"

 [Difference between ng-change and $watch](http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/11/using-ng-change-instead-of-$watch-in-angular/)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try with ng-change ? It call a function when value of ng-model change

```
<input type="search"  ng-change="changeValue()"  ng-model="test" name="test"/>
```

If you want to know wich field call the function you can add the name as string parameter

```
<input type="search"  ng-change="changeValue('field1')"  ng-model="field1" name="field1"/>
```

In the controller don't forget to put the function changeValue in the scope

```
 $scope.changeValue = function(fieldname){
    switch (fieldname){
        case 'field1' : .... break;
        case 'field2' : .... break;     
        case 'field3' : .... break;
        ...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you compare the copied object against the original form data, and you want to check for changes, you can use angular.equals.

```
 angular.equals(formObj, formObjCopy)
```

This will do a deep compare of the object and its nested sub-properties, and return true if the object hasn't changed.